# Combo box does not return correct results

Tags: ms-access, vba

The following Row Source for my combo box displays correct results except when the Client (this is the link to tblClient) is 661. In all other cases is gives correct results. 661 is the PK for tblClient.  In this case, the field is blank, yet it does actually have the correct PK for tblReceipts. I know this because a command button linking the combo box to frmreceipts works correctly. I have triple checked my data and have linked the Row Source to an Access Query, rather than pure SQL. The 'Access Query returns correct data, leading me to guess that the problem lies not in SQL but on the form or in the combo box. It's important that client 661 functions the same as all other clients except in this one respect. if all else fails, I'll create a separate command button to do what's necessary when 661 is involved. Very Heath Robinson, I know.

```
SELECT tblReceipts.ID, tblClient.ClientID, tblClient.ClientName, tblReceipts.DateRec, tblReceipts.Type, tblReceipts.Amount, tblReceipts.SerialNo
FROM tblReceipts INNER JOIN tblClient ON tblReceipts.ClientLookup = tblClient.ClientID
WHERE (((tblClient.ClientID)=IIf([Forms]![frmDisclosure]![Client]=661,417,[Forms]![frmDisclosure]![Client])))
ORDER BY tblClient.ClientName, tblReceipts.DateRec DESC;
```

Further information: the column count for my combo box is 7, with the first being the PK for the client. The column width is normally zero, but if I make it 1cm, client 661 correctly shows PK 417. Unsatisfactory for most records of course, but interesting.

Comment: Edit accepted but 'Client' is on my form as the link to tblClient. Can't see how I can edit my question so: the 'Access Query' returns correct results so perhaps the problem is on the form or the combo box.

Comment: What is frmDisclosure's RecordSource?

Comment: What type of field is [Forms]![frmDisclosure]![Client] and is that linked to a query or sql in its recordsource. Can you debug.print  [Forms]![frmDisclosure]![Client]  when the Client is updated (After_Update)

Comment: [Forms]![frmDisclosure]![Client] is Number – Long Integer. It’s a lookup field connecting to tblClient. Pleas excuse my lack of expertixe but can you help me with Can you debug.print [Forms]![frmDisclosure]![Client] when the Client is updated (After_Update). There are no Events in the combo box.

Comment: `frmDisclosure` is a single form? The IIf in the WHERE clause is a bit unusual, perhaps you need a `Combobox.Requery` in the `Form_Current` event to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> .. my combo box displays correct results except when the Client ... is 661

Well, you substitute 661 with 417, so you will never receive data for 661, and it is the data for 417 you should double-check.

Try to run this to retrieve the data for 417:

```
SELECT tblReceipts.ID, tblClient.ClientID, tblClient.ClientName, tblReceipts.DateRec, tblReceipts.Type, tblReceipts.Amount, tblReceipts.SerialNo
FROM tblReceipts INNER JOIN tblClient ON tblReceipts.ClientLookup = tblClient.ClientID
WHERE (tblClient.ClientID=417)
ORDER BY tblClient.ClientName, tblReceipts.DateRec DESC;
```

The try to display the current ClientID:

```
SELECT 
    tblReceipts.ID, 
    tblClient.ClientID, 
    tblClient.ClientName, 
    tblReceipts.DateRec, 
    tblReceipts.Type, 
    tblReceipts.Amount, 
    tblReceipts.SerialNo,
    [Forms]![frmDisclosure]![Client] As CurrentClientID
FROM 
    tblReceipts 
INNER JOIN 
    tblClient 
    ON tblReceipts.ClientLookup = tblClient.ClientID
WHERE 
    (((tblClient.ClientID)=IIf([Forms]![frmDisclosure]![Client]=661,417,[Forms]![frmDisclosure]![Client])))
ORDER BY 
    tblClient.ClientName, tblReceipts.DateRec DESC;
```

Now, study the retrieved CurrentClientID values.

Comment: I don't want data for 661, I want data for 417, and i get nothing.

Comment: That will always give data for client 417. I want 417 when the client is 661, otherwise, the client as stated.

Comment: I know. But you wrote you didn't receive any data, and then you asked how to debug this. To debug, you have to start somewhere "which works", and then move step by step. So do the query retrieve data for 417?

Comment: Yes it did. When I said it will always give data for 417, I had tested your suggestion (even though your suggestion was how it was before I tried to get it to do what my question says. When I asked how to debug I didn't mean what you seem to think I meant.

Comment: Run the adjusted query above where the ClientID from the from will be displayed.

Comment: This delivers corrscr results if used as a standard Access query in 'All Access Objects'. I have already achieved this  as mentioned in my question. But on the form the combo box just delivers a blank. As I said, I think there is a problem on the form or in the combo box.

Comment: But what values are returned in CurrentClientID from the query above?

Comment: Thought I had already explained. The query on its own delivers the required results: If the client is 661, the query delivers 417. Otherwise it delivers the client. So, trying to be clear: it the client is 234, the query delivers 234. if the client is 661, the query delivers 417. It doesn't work when used on the form.

Comment: Sorry, can't follow. You wrote: "The following Row Source for my combo box displays correct results except when the Client (this is the link to tblClient) is 661. In all other cases is gives correct results." Now you say it delivers correctly "on its own", but returns nothing "when used on the form".

Comment: I mean when I run the query as a stand-alone query, not as part of the form. I'm entirely self-taught so please bear with me. If I open my database, press F11, I get a list of 'All Access Objects' - All tables, queries, forms, modules in the database. In the list of queries I have set up a query on its own - picking up the Client ID from the form. Let us call this qry1. Note that when I use the form, the row source for my combo box has its own SQL, not linked to the query earlier referred to. Let us call this qry2. They are identical but qry1 does what I want and the form/qry 2 does not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115558/discussion-between-great-crosby-and-gustav).

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by changing the row source of the combo box in the On Current event for the form.

```
Select Case Client
    Case 661
        Me.ReceiptsLookup.RowSource = "SELECT tblReceipts.ID, tblClient.ClientID, tblClient.ClientName, tblReceipts.DateRec, tblReceipts.Type, tblReceipts.Amount, tblReceipts.SerialNo " & _
                                      "FROM tblReceipts INNER JOIN tblClient ON tblReceipts.ClientLookup = tblClient.ClientID " & _
                                      "WHERE (((tblClient.ClientID) = 417)) " & _
                                      "ORDER BY tblClient.ClientName, tblReceipts.DateRec DESC "
```

End Select